# CORS cookies not setting by browser , cookies are present in response

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, cross-domain, session-cookies

I am sending http request to API endpoint of node.js server, this response is containing cookies and showing in mozilla debugger. I am sending this request through **localhost.org** or by my virtual host e.g **myapp.example.com**.
I tried AJAX XMLHTTPRequest and angular http as well
also add **xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}** for AJAX 
**credentials: 'include'** for fetch, etc.

But cookies are not being set by browser, I am trying this for 2 days but this problem is not yet resolved.

*this is util function which send ajax request*

```
function sendServerRequest(url,method,data) {
return new Promise(function ( resolve ) {
    resolve($.ajax({
        url,
        method: method || 'GET',
        data,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function ( data ) {
            return data
        },
        error: function ( err ) {
            try {
                let responseStatus = err.responseJSON
                if ( responseStatus.status === sessionExpires ) {
                    sessionExpireCall(responseStatus.message)
                }
            } catch ( e ) {
                console.log('Failed to get response');
            }
        }
    }));
 })
}
```

**Response Raw**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 13000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 12996
Date: 2019-06-26 06:17:56
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1561533343
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.10.3
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,             
Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
set-cookie: true
set-cookie: driverId=c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c; Max-Age=3600;       
Domain=192.168.10.3; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 26 Jun 2019 07:17:56 GMT
set-cookie: driverName=kamran; Max-Age=3600; Domain=192.168.10.3; Path=/; 
Expires=Wed, 26 Jun 2019 07:17:56 GMT
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AX- syECgzpFEZhh4d5B_xfStUoYPrO3p1.%2FPj%2BMo7UnaZto6OGoP%2BOjdKvrJ%2F3Fm%2Bn1BJ%2FXU7Qdh8; Domain=192.168.10.3; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 26 Jun 2019 07:17:56 GMT; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 34
ETag: W/"22-tpsDmOyD3m/F84/JvyRCwDCbeY8"
Connection: keep-alive

{"detail":"verified","status":200}
```

**Request Raw**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/driverboard/verifycode? 
mobile=923002222222&vcode=2609 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://192.168.10.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.10.3/capptin-driverboard/verification.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: true
```

[image: http request snapshot]

Comment: I think the problem is that the Cookie domain `.localhost.org` is not equal what in the browsers page is. Could you check it? I'll post a detailed answer afterwards on the reasons etc if this is the case.

Comment: no i also tried with localhost and with the IP (192.168.1.3)
every thing works fine when i open website from localhost and request my server with localhost , or web opened from (192.168.1.3) request to server at 192.168.1.3

Comment: this problem only occurs when web open from different address and request to different url for example if web is opened from 192.168.1.3 and request at localhost
then it is not storing cookies , even cookies are present in response as showing in the snapshot

Comment: Could you include a raw HTTP request and response in the question?

Comment: yeah sure @Mark

Comment: I cannnot see the raw request. Did I miss something?

Comment: please check again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CORS is not about cookies, CORS about HTTP headers. It allows making cross-domain requests(from one domain to another. For example from myapp.example.com to google.com). Cookies only send to the same domain, for example from myapp.example.com you can send cookies to the same domain .example.com

Docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: thanks @Alexey i understand , but i want to save cookies in the browser 
my request is from myapp.example.com to somedomain,com 
i also add required headers in the request and response as well

Answer (score 2):

You can Append the cookie to your response with "/" as path.

add cookie in c# core. Append it to response:

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append(cookieNameAsString, cookieValue, new CookieOptions()
    {
        Expires = time,
         Path = "/",
     });
```

or create a cookie in javascript:

```
document.cookie = "cookieNameAsString='cookieValue'; max-age=time;";
```

Comment: Make sure your Expires date is in the future. Can you show your code?

Comment: i have posted raw request and response 
you can see all the required headers are present and cookies are also set in response

Comment: i updated my question and add the code of the ajax request